# Вывод последних сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

`reciver-id | sender-id | date | text  
1 | 44 | 21.12.2011 | qwerty  
1 | 2 | 23.12.2011 | qwerty  
1 | 3 | 21.12.2011 | qwerty  
1 | 2 | 15.12.2011 | qwerty  
1 | 44 | 20.12.2011 | qwerty`

Есть такая таблица сообщений. Как мне составить запрос, чтобы mysql вытаскивал только последнее сообщение от каждого пользователя, которые отправляли сообщения?

Из этой таблицы должен получиться вот такой массив:

`reciver-id | sender-id | date | text  
1 | 44 | 21.12.2011 | qwerty   
1 | 2 | 23.12.2011 | qwerty  
1 | 3 | 21.12.2011 | qwerty`

Comment: А есть в этом смысл? зачем нужна информация о последнем сообщении каждого пользователя? я просто не представляю для чего, и мне интересно.

Comment: Элементарно добавить в таблицу колонку message_id обязательно с автозаполнением (Auto_increment!), и при группировке записей, вытаскивать от каждого пользователя самый большой message_id

Comment: а как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать указанной в вопросе структуре таблицы, то:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN
( -- Подзапрос группирует отправителей и выводит дату последнего сообщения
    SELECT  `sender-id`, MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY 1
) t2 ON (t2.`sender-id` = t1.`sender-id`) AND (t2.`date` = t1.`date`)
```

Только нужно учитывать, что если тип столбца DATE, то в один и тот-же день одним и тем-же  пользователем могут быть отправлены несколько сообщений. В этом случае запрос выведет все  несколько. На вашем месте в таблицу сообщений я добавил бы автоинкрементальный ключ. Он стал бы залогом уникальности для каждого сообщения, и на него можно было бы опираться при выборке последних.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(Date) AS d,Sender_ID
INTO #Temp
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Sender_ID

SELECT *
FROM TABLE _t
INNER JOIN #Temp t ON t.d=_t.Date AND t.Sender_ID = _t.Sender_ID

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: В MySQL `INTO` используется в конце запроса, и только для передачи единичного значения в переменные. Для создания временной таблицы на базе запроса используется `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table ENGINE = <engine> AS SELECT * FROM table_name`.

Comment: ужасно. приму к сведению

Answer (score 1):

```
reciver-id | sender-id | display | date | text
```

Добавить к примеру display и при добавлении нового сообщения - всем сообщениям имеющим значение 1 делать апдейт на 0 а новому сообщению записывать 1. и соответственно запрос `WHERE display > 0`

Для добавления есть `ALTER TABLE *table* ALTER COLUMN *column*` - на всяк случай)

Comment: Честно говоря такое поле есть, называется status, прочитано сообщение или нет.

Comment: новое != прочитанное =)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sender-id, max(date) from table group by sender-id
```

чувствую, что где-то ошибся, но смысл такой вот =)

Comment: В `WHERE` нельзя использовать агрегатные функции

Comment: а так?) давно уже не с бд не работал =)